# AngularJS send image to directive (and show directive)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my view i'm binding to file upload so:

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().photoChanged(this.files)"/>
```

and i have such directive:

```
  .directive('imageCrop', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div style="display: none;"><p>Image!</p></div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.text('this is the imageCrop directive');
      }
    };
  });
```

how could i in controller's method make this directive visible and send to it my image?

which practice is the best in this case?

Comment: Either compile in controller's method with $compile and add into document, or use ng-if in place where the directive is (ommiting display: none in template for both cases).

Comment: @IvoPeterka with controller is not clear...

Comment: Thinking about it, compiling new directive with each new image would only bring issues with freeing compiled directives and memory demands, so it is not good way anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject `ngModel` to your directive like

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().photoChanged(this.files)"/>
<imageCrop ngModel="image" />
```

In your `photoChanged` function, bind the uploaded files to model `image`. Besides, require `ngModel` in your directive definition.